# How to solve $2z^5 + z^4 -6z^2 + z + 1 = 0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$2z^5 + z^4 -6z^2 + z + 1 = 0$$
z is complex number.
I tried to make factor but i didn't find.

Comment: I would substitute $$z=x+iy$$

Comment: And I would downvote it

Comment: A nice answer, indeed, then say what you would do?

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2z%5E5%2Bz%5E4-6z%5E2%2Bz%2B1%3D0 might help

Comment: The solution in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2z%5E5%2Bz%5E4-6z%5E2%2Bz%2B1%3D0&t=crmtb01) doesn't look particularly "nice."  I think you have to settle for numerical solution.

Comment: Even WA wrote the solutions in exact form as $z=$ _near_ $x=-0.33416.$ Seems unlikely that we will find an exact solution.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Look again.  $z=1$ is not a solution.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Was sich überhaupt sagen lässt, lässt sich klar sagen; und wovon man nicht reden kann, darüber muss man schweigen.

Comment: A very good sentence in German, nice to hear.

Comment: I agree with the last post of greedoid in this case. The sentence is by Wittgenstein, if memory doesn't fail me.

Answer (score 4):

Using [a CAS](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), the Galois group of this polynomial is $S_5$, so the roots can't be expressed using radicals. You need to use numerical methods.

Input:

```
Q := Rationals();
P<z> := PolynomialRing(Q);
G, R, S := GaloisGroup(2*z^5+z^4-6*z^2+z+1);
G;
```

Output:

```
Symmetric group G acting on a set of cardinality 5
Order = 120 = 2^3 * 3 * 5
```